# Python 2.7.10 conflicts with ArcGIS Desktop 10.1

Tags: python, arcgis

Last week I uninstalled Python 2.7.10 for 64 bit Windows OS on my computer which already has had Python 2.7.2 installed that came with ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 under "c:\Python27\".

The new 2.7.10 was installed in a different folder "c:\Program Files\Python-2.7.10\"

Since 2.7.10 was installed I have had problems running the existing models built in Arctools on ArcMap and constantly failed to open ArcCatalog 10.1. My guess is ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 could probably conflict with Python 2.7.10.

I think ArcMap is currently using 2.7.10 instead of 2.7.2 as it gives me `"sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=10, releaselevel='final', serial=0)"` from running the "sys.version_info" command on the Python window within ArcMap. I can only import arcgis but not arcpy from "geoprocessing" -> "Python" windows.

Is there a way to tell ArcMap/ArcCatalog to re-use 2.7.2 by fixing Windows registry or configuring some settings in ArcGIS?

Comment: Have you checked your PATH environment variable to see if Python 2.7.2 is still there? Maybe ArcGIS is only using the default Python which might have been changed during installation of 2.7.10

Comment: It's very weird. I managed to uninstall 2.7.10 and re-install 2.7.2. When I tried to print the current version, it still prints out 2.7.10...

Comment: That does sound weird... Maybe try starting up a Python interpreter from command prompt and see what version you get

Comment: Yes. The Python interpreter from cmd prompt printed 2.7.10 even if I have reinstalled 2.7.2 (32 bit) to this directory...

Comment: Ah I see. You'll need to search environment variables, then edit the PATH user variable so that C:\Python27 comes before the other version. You could also consider removing the entry for the new Python, but I'm not sure if this will have side-effects. If the old version (installed with ArcGIS) comes up in cmd then I think you'll get what you're looking for

Comment: ArcGIS installed both 32-bit and 64-bit version Python. The affected Python is the 32-bit one. The 64-bit Python interpreter still prints out 2.7.2 while it is the 32-bit one that prints out 2.7.10. I installed a new 32-bit 2.7.10 the other day on a different directory but it affected the ArcGIS 32-bit Python, and this is where I got the problem. Then I re-installed 2.7.2 to the ArcGIS 32-bit Python directory. The PATH has the 64-bit Python by default which is 2.7.2. Any idea?